# Android RecyclerView Selected Item Transition Animation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-recyclerview

Disclosure up front, this is a school project.

I have a list of items in a grid layout via a RecyclerView, like such:

[image]

When you tap on an item, it pops off a DialogFragment, like such (forgive the unstyled dialog):

[image]

This happens with no animation, which is the normal even on 5.0 devices. I'm trying to achieve something to the effect of the animation that occurs in the Google Play Music app when an album is tapped. (the "container" holding the album in the list you pick it from appears to "expand" from the location of the container and fills the screen with a new fragment)

I've seen a number of threads about animating an expansion of the list in list form, but not for this kind of animation where a new fragment is popped off, and with animation in general being a weak point of mine, I'm somewhat lost as to how to achieve this effect. More to the point, is it even possible with a dialog fragment?

Answer (score 0):

That is android activity transition

You can refer the link below

https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html

It can be pop-up style... But it has lots more work to do...start with activity basic first...

Comment: It would be horrifically wasteful to pop off an activity for something I'm currently using a dialog fragment for; that's the crux of my question, if those activity animations can be applied to fragments without refactoring my code in such a costly manner.

Comment: An popup is actually same cost with activity, it make new window even it is a DialogFragment, you can look into the source code of the DialogFragment and Dialog, correct me if I am wrong.